# (ipcMain Eletronjs) event is not defined

Tags: javascript, electron, ipc

Recently I've been developing a windows application (using Electronjs) that encrypts files. I want it so that when I press the first button in the renderer it sends to the main process asking it to open the open file dialog. I tried this code.

**renderer.js**

```
firstButton.addEventListener("click", openFile)
function openFile() {
    ipc.send('open-the-open-dialogue');
}
ipc.on('file-picked', function(event, arg) {
    console.log(arg);
}
```

**main.js**

```
ipc.on('open-the-open-dialogue',  
    function () {
      var filenames = dialog.showOpenDialogSync({ properties: ['openFile'] });
      if(!filenames) {
        dialog.showErrorBox("ERROR!", "You didn't pick a file to encrypt.")
      }
      event.reply('file-opened', filenames[0]);
    }
);
```

When I tried this code it came up with an error saying event is not defined. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your IPC commands are wrong. You should use `ipcRenderer` on renderer process and `ipcMain` on main process.

example:

> Main.js
>
> ```
> const { ipcMain } = require('electron')
> ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', (event, arg) => {
>   console.log(arg) // prints "ping"
>   event.reply('asynchronous-reply', 'pong')
> })
>
> ipcMain.on('synchronous-message', (event, arg) => {
>   console.log(arg) // prints "ping"
>   event.returnValue = 'pong'
> })
> ```
>
> Renderer.js
>
> ```
> const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
> console.log(ipcRenderer.sendSync('synchronous-message', 'ping')) // prints "pong"
>
> ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-reply', (event, arg) => {
>   console.log(arg) // prints "pong"
> })
> ```

You can read about electron [IPC from here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main)

Answer (score 0):

```
ipcRenderer.on('open-the-open-dialogue',  

    // ipc Listner's callback function should have 2 parameters.

    function (event, args) {
      var filenames = dialog.showOpenDialogSync({ properties: ['openFile'] });

      if(!filenames) {
        dialog.showErrorBox("ERROR!", "You didn't pick a file to encrypt.")
      }

      // You are sending through `file-opened` channel
      // But where is listener? Maybe `file-picked`

      event.reply('file-picked', filenames[0]);
    }
);
```

Comment: @Andrew gad,  `event.reply('file-opened', filenames[0]);` You are replying through `flie-opened`

Comment: But at your renderer, not listening this `file-opened` just `file-picked`